# How to get materialised result from Akka Stream Graph?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm trying to figure out how to get materialised result from the scala Akka Stream graph.

I'm using `"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream-experimental" % "1.0"`.

I looked at the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala.html) but could not find any example.

So, let's say I have a code

```
val g = FlowGraph.closed() { implicit builder=>
  import FlowGraph.Implicits._

  val in = Source.apply(1 until 10)
  val plus = Flow[Int].map(_ + 10)
  val out = Sink.fold[Seq[Int], Int](Nil){
    case (acc, num) => if (num % 2 == 0) acc :+ num else acc
  }

  in ~> plus ~> out
}

val result = g.run()
```

I would like to get the result from the graph `g` but it returns Unit. How to deal with that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: You may want to look at how you're creating the flow too... I think `RunnableGraph` might be better for your situation and then `run` would return the `Mat` type.

Otherwise, try looking at the `.mapMaterializedValue(v => ...)` calls in this section of the manual (specifically line 40):

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala/stream-flows-and-basics.html#Combining_materialized_values

I think that's what you're trying to do.

EDIT: It's also used in this chat application i found (line 54):

https://github.com/jrudolph/akka-http-scala-js-websocket-chat/blob/master/backend/src/main/scala/example/akkawschat/Chat.scala

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can't do it from the `FlowGraph`. You need to create all your flows externally and then use them inside the `FlowGraph`.

```
val in = Source.apply(1 until 10)
val plus = Flow[Int].map(_ + 10)
val out = Sink.fold[Seq[Int], Int](Nil) {
  case (acc, num) => if (num % 2 == 0) acc :+ num else acc
}
```

So, the code would look something like

```
val g = FlowGraph.closed(in, plus, out)((_, _, _)) { implicit builder => (src, f, dst) =>
  import FlowGraph.Implicits._
  src ~> f ~> dst
}
```

Another way, which I found simpler is to do

```
val z = in.via(plus).toMat(out)(Keep.right)
```